# Why 1 property of undefined in the React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

folks! Its again me with my API troubles)

So in this very moment im stuck on this chunk of code:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {NativeSelect, FormControl} from '@material-ui/core';
import styles from './CountryPicker.module.css';
import {fetchCountries} from '../../api';

const CountryPicker = () => {
    const [fetchedCountries, setFetchedCountries] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            setFetchedCountries(await fetchCountries());
        }

        fetchAPI();
    }, [setFetchedCountries]);


    return (
        <FormControl className={styles.FormControl}>
            <NativeSelect>
                <option value="global">Global</option>
                {fetchedCountries.map((country, i) => <option key={i} value={country}>{country}</option>)}

            </NativeSelect>
        </FormControl>
    )

}

export default CountryPicker;
```

and this also in api index.js :

```
export const fetchCountries = async () => {
    try {
        const {data: {countries}} = await axios.get('${url}/countries');

        return countries.map((country) => country.name);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

So, when I was trying console log, I have this 
[My console log and ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUal9.jpg)

Thanks for reading this, folks, I hope we will figure out this together)

Comment: Can you please provide url to api for better debugging.

Comment: `axios.get()` fails (see console log) with 404. Your `fetchCountries()` function returns nothing (and then `undefined`) if an error is `catch`ed. You set `fetchedCountries` to `undefined` and then `.map()` will fail with the error you report. Either 1) add `return []` when you catch an error or 2) call `setFetchedCountries()` only if `fetchCountries()` returned _something_.

Comment: Can you try like ```{fetchedCountries && fetchedCountries.map( ... ) }``` ??.

Comment: @FerinPatel const url = 'https://covid19.mathdro.id/api'; this api

Comment: @ManirajMurugan iv tried this and I cannot choose different countries, just global

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti try your first advice and it worked, but I still cannot choose countries in picker.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to render it before it is updated causes `undefined.map` -> throws an error

```
 {fetchedCountries && fetchedCountries.length !== 0 && fetchedCountries.map((country, i) => <option key={i} value={country}>{country}</option>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I figure out. It my url in axios.get doesn't work properly, when I change it start worked good
[list countries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqUow.jpg)